# How does Fortify Touchless MSBuild work?

Tags: fortify

I have been trying to setup Fortify Touchless MSBuild. So I do not have to have visual studio installed on my build agent. How does this integration happen? The documentation does not provide any implementation details on this.

I am using Version 17.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the compiler to compile it. Fortify will only participate during the process of building, not build it itself.

I think you misundestood touchless, which the purpoise is make sourceanalyzer work with compilers that are not supported by fortify (like cmake).

The sourceanalyzer touchless build will run the original build script (like build.py) and watch the process to create its own translate files. Of course, it will need the build to work, what means it needs the compiler.

If you really dont want to have visual studio in the machine, you can scan on your VS-having machine, generate translate files, and send it to the analyzer who doesnt needs to build it.

BTW, fortify supports MSBUILD so i just recomend to install VS :)

Comment: If you are compiling a .net framework project in linux with msbuild, Fortify will inform you that it doesn't support linux with msbuild. using 17.20